# math question for book. babbage difference engine

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know you are all going to find this a little strange but I am an author so what the heck. Anyway I have a problem I need help with. As I said I am an author and I am writing a portion in my book that requires a really complex equation. I have to explain what it is first. Ok so this book is based in a futuristic game where the players are actually in the game and can die if they fail. In this ark they are trapped in a music box, and must use a Babbage difference engine in order to unlock the music box. They have to figure out an equation and use it to find the value of the 100 level of the game.

In the game there are one hundred levels and each level increases in difficulty by 10% of the previous level. At the 25th level it increases by 25%. At the 50th level it increases by 50%. At the 75 it increases by 75% and at the hundredth level it increases by 100%. I have already done the calculations for this, and know that the hundredth level is 142,575,457,243,489.8 times the first level. Ridiculous I know.

What I really need to know is what equation I would need to find this value using the Babbage difference engine because the characters need the equation to unlock the music box. I suck at math and have only a rudimentary idea how the Babbage engine works so I need someone who knows more than me to help.

I don't even know if it is possible to find this value with the difference engine and if it isn't please let me know and I will go a different way. As a reward for anyone who does figure this out I will use your name (first name only) as the character who figures out the equation. If you don't want that I understand but I would appreciate any help. if you have any doubts about who I am feel free to look up author L.W. Greenwood on Google. I do intend to publish this book. maybe you could help be part of it and brag to your friends.

thanks for your consideration

LW Greenwood

Comment: Um, no offense, but if you intend to write fiction for profit, then I hope you're treating your paying readers with a bit more respect than you do the volunteer participants on a Q&A site. Capitalize the beginning of sentences! Use some paragraph breaks now and then! Oh, and commas too ...

Comment: Sorry about that. I assure you I do not do that in my books. I didn't figure it would matter for this question, but I suppose I should use a little more professionalism since I am an author.

Comment: If you would like some help on your writing, then I'd suggest that you work harder on your proof-reading to avoid nonsense like "an so author what the heck" and to avoid very long paragraphs. You can have that, from me, for free. If you want detailed help on your mathematics or on the capabilities of Babbage's difference engine then I think you should offer a full acknowledgment and payment for research time.

Comment: Ok fair enough. I will admit that I was looking for a simple solution to my problem however you should understand that there is no profit in this for me. I will likely spend thousands getting this book published and there is no guaranty that I will make a dime off of it. I do work very hard proofreading my book. As far as full acknowledgment I will offer it to anyone who wishes for it but I really have no money to pay for research. So if no one can answer my question I fully understand.

Comment: There is a little `edit` button that you can click that will allow you to improve the poor writing in your post. I suggest you click it.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about the edit button.

Comment: Perhaps we should **all** remember what Dr. Johnson said: "No man but a blockhead ever wrote except for money". Good luck with your book!

Comment: Thanks never heard that quote before, it's good I will remember that. In that case I think I am the blockhead.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you want a result of 142,575,457,243,489.8, then you need a 25% increase not only at step 25, but also at step 26, 27, 28, and so forth up to 49. And then you need twenty-five separate 50% increases followed by twenty-five separate 75% increases. All in all, the number you're computing is

$$ 1.1^{23}\times 1.25 ^{25} \times 1.5^{25} \times 1.75^{25} \times 2
 = 2\frac{(1.1\times 1.25\times 1.5 \times 1.75)^{25}}{1.1^2}
 \approx 142\,575\,457\,243\,489.824 $$

Now, the *Difference Engine* would be completely useless for evaluating this expression. It was (to have been) not a general computing machine, but a specialized tool for computing and typesetting tables of polynomial functions of degrees up to 8. Even if we manage to rewrite the expression above to be a value of such a polynomial, *setting up* a computation of the Difference Engine would have required significantly *more* manual calculations than finding a single value of the polynomial. It would (arguably) have been a labor-saving device if you wanted an entire table with *many* values in them, but for a *single* result it was not of any use.

Presumably the *Analytical Engine* would have been able to carry out the computation, but it was never built, and never even completely designed. It wouldn't have been very fast either -- Wikipedia quotes Ada Lovelace as writing that the expected time to compute a 20-digit multiplication was 3 minutes. That is several times faster than a trained calculator can multiply with pencil and paper, but it's not even *tens* of times faster.

Using [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), it takes only ten multiplications (and then one long division) to evaluate the expression above. Just doing it with pencil and paper to a respectable precision would take around an hour or two at the most. Even if an Analytical Engine existed, it would likely be impossible to develop, debug, and run a program to do it faster than that -- unless one of the character *already* has extensive prior experience with programming the Engine.

Also, neither the Difference Engine or the Analytical Engine would be programmed by supplying it with an "equation". As mentioned before, the Difference Engine wasn't even programmable -- you set it up by putting eight input numbers into the registers, and then when you crank the handle it does the only thing it knows how with them. The programming mechanism for the Analytical Engine was never fully designed, but the program would most likely have been a chain of punched cards.

Comment: Wow thank you. I was starting to doubt whether anyone would attempt to answer my question. I am sorry I did fail to mention that all levels between 25 and 50 would increase by 25% and so on. Thank you for realizing that. I am happy that you answered my question even if I am I bit disappointed that it wouldn't really work on the difference engine. I may still attempt to think of a way to use it since this is supposed to be an incredibly complex lock but as you mentioned the person would have to have prior knowledge of how to use the engine.

Comment: Oh I almost forgot do you want any credit for this. I am still willing to use your name or give you full accreditation if you want. I do appreciate your help regardless of whether I can use it or not. This just means that I will have to do something else to make it work in my book.